# Adding new class to persistence.xml throws java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Object: Restaurants{id=null, name=Subway} is not a known entity type

Tags: jpa, entity, eclipselink, illegalargumentexception, persistence.xml

I created a new entity class, and added it to the `persistence.xml` file.

```
<class>xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.Restaurants</class>
```

When trying to build in Maven, I get this error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Object: Restaurants{id=null, name=Subway} is not a known entity type.
```

How is this caused and how can I solve it? There are no problems with the other entity classes, but just this one.

Comment: Is it annotated as an entity? Are you using Maven profiles for the build?

Comment: @hermitmaster Yes, I have added ´Entity´ to the class. I'm not sure what you mean by "Maven profiles" ? Please, can you explain?

Comment: ´@Entity´ but couldnt use the at sign in the comment above and tag you at the same time.

Comment: In some of our applications we use Maven build profiles that use different persistence.xml files for testing, production, etc.
http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html

Comment: @hermitmaster Thank you! I had added the new entity class to the "persistence.xml" file but forgot to add it to the "test-persistence.xml" file, and thus why I got error while testing. Thank you, and please "answer my question" with what you commented earlier, so I can accept it and you can earn points.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In some of our applications we use Maven build profiles that use different persistence.xml files for testing, production, etc. http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html